# How to find and replace some text using Regex in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have the below script and I am trying to replace the line that begins with 10 using the measurements from line that starts with 05. But the pattern used in $mat is not working even though it works in notepad++.
This is what I want it to look like

> ```
> 0100031     35327                    00002228            2144064             20200801  0430035604050430 0000000000  00BLT1  00000 
> 0500031     35327                    V4A                 +019.8  0.85220     14702.0     14643.0     01                           
> 1000031     35327                    V4A            80   +019.8  0.85220     14702.0     14643.0     V4A                 1        
> 0500031     35327                    V4A                 +019.0  0.85220     15698.0     15647.0     01                           
> 1000031     35327                    V4A            80   +019.0  0.85220     15698.0     15647.0     V4A                 1        
> 2000031     35327                    00002228            2144064           0052299.0   0052115.0   0017     035327
> ```

```
  $data = "0100031     35327                    00002228            2144064             20200801  0430035604050430 0000000000  00BLT1  00000 
0500031     35327                    V4A                 +019.8  0.85220     14702.0     14643.0     01                           
1000031     35327                    V4A            80   +018.8  0.85040     11026.0     10991.0     V2C                 1        
1000031     35327                    V4A            80   +022.9  0.85760     03676.0     03652.0     V4B                 1        
0500031     35327                    V4A                 +019.0  0.85220     15698.0     15647.0     01                           
1000031     35327                    V4A            80   +017.9  0.85040     11774.0     11746.0     V2C                 1        
1000031     35327                    V4A            80   +022.1  0.85760     03924.0     03901.0     V4B                 1        
2000031     35327                    00002228            2144064           0052299.0   0052115.0   0017     035327                
"
    
    $data
    Write-Host ""
    
    Write-Host "Replacing number of lines"
    Write-Host ""
    $summaryline= $data -replace '(^0500031\s{5}\d{5}\s{20}V4A.{60})(\s\d{2}\s)(.{26})','$1 01 $3'
    $summaryline
    Write-Host ""
    
    Write-Host "Matched lines"
    Write-Host ""
    $mat=$summaryline -match '^0500031.{30}V4A\s{17}(?<measure>.{43}).+\r\n10.{55}'
    $mat
    Write-Host ""
```

Comment: `^` only matches the very start of a multi-line string. If you want to it to match at the start of the individual lines inside that string, use the following inline option at the start of the regex: `(?m)`.

Comment: Either add the multiline option like @mklement0 suggests, or split the input data into individual strings before attempting to replace anything: `$data = $data -split '\r?\n'`

Comment: Thanks guys. That was the problem. Does someone want to post that as an answer?